# Currency converter - Nothing happens when I press the button

Tags: html, function, button, input

I am trying to make a currency converter. When I type in a number in the input box and then press one off the buttons nothing happens. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When checking if a button is clicked in Javascript, it uses a function callback to do so. So, where you have:

`if (KnappBL.onclick) {...}`

Javascript is looking for:

`KnappBL.onclick = function() {...}`

Then, inside of the function callback, you can execute your code to show that the currency has changed.

EDIT: You can find more information about the onClick callback on Mozilla's website [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick).

Answer (score 0):

The thing that stands out the most at a glance would be the absence of a function in your javascript. Try adding something along the lines of the code below (fyi I have not tested this so you may need to tweak it to fit your application). :) hope this leads you in the right direction.

```
function convert(amount, convertfrom, convertTo) {
if ***********************
else if ************************
else if ************************
}
```